# SpringBoot JPA repository saveAll throws write conflict in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, jpa, transactions

I have a Spring Boot application code similar to one given below, it tries to save a list of entities in MongoDB, but I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-20" org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 112 (WriteConflict): 'WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.' on server 127.X.X.X:XXXXX. The full response is {"errorLabels": ["TransientTransactionError"]
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 112 (WriteConflict): 'WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.' on server 127.X.X.X:XXXXX. The full response is {"errorLabels": ["TransientTransactionError"]
```

So, what should I do to avoid this error/exception?

**Code:**

```
@Transactional
public synchronized void myMethod(List<MyEntity> myEntities) {
    saveEntities(myEntities);
}

public void saveEntities(List<MyEntity> myEntities) {
    myRepository.saveAll(myEntities);
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation or `javax.transaction.Transactional`?

Comment: @viniciusmfelix, org.springframework.transaction.annotation

Answer (score 2):

Java mongo driver (`mongo-driver-sync-4.4.2`) supports retry for WriteConflicts error:
`ClientSessionImpl.withTransaction(final TransactionBody<T> transactionBody, final TransactionOptions options)`

```
outer:
        while (true) {
            T retVal;
            try {
                startTransaction(options);
                retVal = transactionBody.execute();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                if (transactionState == TransactionState.IN) {
                    abortTransaction();
                }
                if (e instanceof MongoException) {
                    if (((MongoException) e).hasErrorLabel(TRANSIENT_TRANSACTION_ERROR_LABEL)
                            && ClientSessionClock.INSTANCE.now() - startTime < MAX_RETRY_TIME_LIMIT_MS) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                throw e;
            }
            if (transactionState == TransactionState.IN) {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        commitTransaction();
                        break;
                    } catch (MongoException e) {
                        clearTransactionContextOnError(e);
                        if (ClientSessionClock.INSTANCE.now() - startTime < MAX_RETRY_TIME_LIMIT_MS) {
                            applyMajorityWriteConcernToTransactionOptions();

                            if (!(e instanceof MongoExecutionTimeoutException)
                                    && e.hasErrorLabel(UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION_COMMIT_RESULT_LABEL)) {
                                continue;
                            } else if (e.hasErrorLabel(TRANSIENT_TRANSACTION_ERROR_LABEL)) {
                                continue outer;
                            }
                        }
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            }
            return retVal;
        }
```

Notice `if (e.hasErrorLabel(TRANSIENT_TRANSACTION_ERROR_LABEL)` redirects logic to `outer` which is to start the whole block again.

However, Spring Boot doesn't make use of `withTransaction` to start a transaction, at least as far as I can see from using `Transactional` annotation.

The only way is to retry at application level. One way is `Retryable`

```
@Retryable(
        value = UncategorizedMongoDbException.class,
        exceptionExpression = "#{message.contains('WriteConflict error')}",
        maxAttempts = 12, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 500))
```

Make sure to apply it on methods that executes database logic only, otherwise, it can cause unwanted behaviour such as repeat certain non-database operation multiple times when `WriteConflicts` occurred